# How to set postgres password using ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible, devops

Usually I do :

```
sudo -su postgres
psql
\password
\q
```

to change postgres password. Now I want to automate this step using ansible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ansible postgresql_user module will help to set/reset the database user password. Here is the sample

```
- name: pd reset database user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user: 
    db: test
    name: test
    password: ""
```

For Reference, here is ansible link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_user_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-user-module